MSAL protectedResourceMap VERB based configuration
I'm looking to configure protectedResourceMap with MSAL to differentiate between HTTP verbs. Specifically, I want to set up an open POST endpoint and a protected GET endpoint.
Requirements:
Anonymous POST: When a button is clicked, allow an anonymous action to log that a product has been bought.
Authenticated POST: If the user is logged in, also add the purchase to their account history.
Authenticated GET: Fetching purchase history should only be available to logged-in users.

protectedResourceMap: new Map([
           // Other entries...
          [
            'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/cart',
            [
              'https://proficiento.onmicrosoft.com/proficiento-api/write',
              'https://proficiento.onmicrosoft.com/proficiento-api/read',
            ],
          ],

Can I configure protectedResourceMap to differentiate between POST and GET requests for these endpoints?
I know i can make it manually, but i dont want to :)

protectedResourceMap maps resorce URL's to scope and doesn't take into account the HTTP method used. (GET, POST, PATCH, etc)
